# why not show exact value when Int value start from zero/0?

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Method{
    
        String name ;
        int Num ;
        
        void text() {
            System.out.println(" Hello this code is running coding by "+ name+" number " +Num);
        }
        
    
}
public class MethodClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Method Object = new Method();
        
        Object.name = " NAHIAN " ;
        
        Object.Num = 0123 ;
        
        Object.text();
        
    }

}
```

Result show:

```
 Hello this code is running coding by  NAHIAN  number 83
```

But the `83` should be `0123`

Comment: Just for printing purposes change Num to String type

Comment: I got it.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

when you add a 0 in front, it is refering to an octa (base8) value.
So 0123 is 83 in dec (base10)

To print out a number in octa. You can convert it to string using the following

```
String convertedString = Integer.toOctalString(0123);

System.out.println("The octa value is " + convertedString);
```

you can refer to https://www.javatpoint.com/java-decimal-to-octal for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use String in Num variable instead of integer.

```
    String name ;
    String Num ;
    void text() {
        System.out.println(" Hello this code is running coding by "+ name+" number " +Num);}
```